# Use closure compiler with compiled vue.js templates

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, google-closure-compiler

Is it possible to use google closure compiler with a compiled Vue.js template?

The culprit is that a compiled vue template uses "with", as in:

```
with(this){/** render function here **/}
```

... and closure compiler does not like that and thus complains with:

```
The with statement cannot be used in strict mode.
```

However, I am not sure if this is really due to strict mode, because in the sourcecode (packed with webpack) there is no `"use strict";` in the offending function:

```
/***/ "./my/compiled/vue/template":
/***/ (function(module, exports) {
    module.exports = {
      render: function(){with(this){ /** render function here **/ }},
      staticRenderFns: []
    };
/***/ })
```

Now, the question is if there is a way to make this compile in closure compiler? Think the most easiest way would be to tell the compiler to pass through that code without doing anything to it (unminimized code runs just fine, so it seems to be valid), but it seems there is no such option.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I can't reproduce this (the build output of the default Vue-CLI generated project does not contain `with`). What's the demo code you're building?

Comment: @tony19: the `with` is used when you are compiling a vue.js template to a render function. And closure compiler simply seems to refuse to compile anything containing `with(..){...}`

Comment: I have two render functions, yet no `with` in the build output. See my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/render-function-troubleshoot). What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know, for me any compiled render function basically starts with `with(this)`. Also see https://vuejs-tips.github.io/compiler/ Just enter any vue template and look at the compiled code to the right. I mean if there is a way to compile without `with` that would be nice as well. Will take a look at your repo!

Comment: So I tried your repo and I think this is different to what I do. So you seem to add a concrete `render()` funktion instead of compiling the `.vue` template. That's not what I do, instead I want to use the vueJS compiler, which in turn always seems to produce that `with` statement. Any other ideas?

Comment: In a Vue CLI project, the .vue template is automatically built by the Vue CLI tooling. Can you update the question to show the original code and how you're compiling it? A github repo would be helpful.

Comment: @tony19, as I see it you are not really using the vuejs template compiler in your example. I am pretty sure that if you use it (and I have to) there is the same output as I described. I am sure there is no error here on my side, and you can easily reproduce the issue by generating *any* render function using the website I mentioned (or doing it manually via CLI or by using the node JS API or whatever) and then feed the result to the online closure compiler service. So the real question is how to compile such a function using closure compiler (if possible at all!)

Comment: @tony19, seems we were both right! Indeed there seem to be multiple ways to compile .vue templates, just depends on the loader you use with webpack (see my anser below). Thanks for helping me finding the right track!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think I know now how to solve this. Turns out that indeed, with compiled .vue templates there seem to be different outputs depending on how you build it. Since I just had to compile templates - but no full scale single file components - I used the simpler `vue-template-compiler-loader` which uses the official compiler and produces the problematic output I described. Now, I tried to build with the more complex `vue-loader` (which is more tailored to single file components) and it seems it also works with files that are "template only". And it seems like the output of that loader is different, as the render functions produced contain no `with(this)`!

This code now compiled without a problem in closure compiler, and first test runs in IE10 (my "lowest target") indicate that the build is just fine now!

Kudos to @tony19 for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: so... did it make your javascript even smaller than the regular compile?